# How to show a form view by clicking on a record in a many2many field without lifting a modal panel

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I have a form with a `Many2many` field and I'm showing it as a tree view:

[image]

By clicking on a record in the `Many2many` field mentioned above, the form of the corresponding model is lifted in a modal panel, as expected:

[image]

I can't find a way to click on a record of the `Many2many` field, instead of lifting a wizard, I will have the form view corresponding to the model of that `Many2many` field, without lifting a popup. In other words, this way:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an action method on the model and extend the tree view showing this as button. This method should return an action which opens the record in a form view. That's the only "easy" way to do that, with the current Odoo framework.

A little example:

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'

    name = fields.Char()

class MyOtherModel(models.Model)
    _name = 'my.other.model'

    name = fields.Char
    my_model_ids = fields.Many2many(
        comodel_name='my.model')

    @api.multi
    def action_show_record(self):
        # only use on singletons
        self.ensure_one()
        return {
            'name': self.name,
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'my.model',
            'context': self.env.context,
            # don't open a popup
            'target': 'current'
        }
```

and the view of my.other.model

```xml
<record id="my_other_model_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">my.other.model.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">my.other.model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="name" />
                    <field name="my_model_ids">
                        <tree>
                            <field name="name" />
                            <button name="action_show_record" type="object"
                                string="Open" icon="an-font-awesome-icon" />
                        </tree>
                    </field>
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Very good explanation, but I'm looking for an option that doesn't have to use a button in the registry. Does this variant exist?

Comment: Then you have to change/extend the Javascript part of Odoo. I can't help you with that.